# Spree: When overriding helper, methods from other helpers are unavailable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I'm trying to override `link_to_cart` method from BaseHelper in Spree (version 2.1.9.beta).
I created `base_helper_decorator.rb` in `app/helpers/spree` and copied there the method that I want to modify (from [spree/core/app/helpers/spree/base_helper.rb](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/e03dde43527586e78860be6813c17771f4a50111/core/app/helpers/spree/base_helper.rb)):

```
# app/helpers/spree/base_helper_decorator.rb
Spree::BaseHelper.module_eval do
  def link_to_cart(text = nil)
    text = text ? h(text) : Spree.t('cart')
    css_class = nil

    if simple_current_order.nil? or simple_current_order.item_count.zero?
      text = "#{text}: (#{Spree.t('empty')})"
      css_class = 'empty'

(...)

    end
  end
end
```

Now any request to the server causes the error:  `undefined local variable or method 'simple_current_order' for #<#<Class:0x007fdea921b828>:0x007fdea22a1128>`.

`simple_current_order` is defined in [core/lib/spree/core/controller_helpers/order.rb](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/e03dde43527586e78860be6813c17771f4a50111/core/lib/spree/core/controller_helpers/order.rb)

What should I do to make this method available in the BaseHelper override?

Comment: probably unrelated, but why are you using a beta version of an old version of Spree?

Comment: One of the extensions I'm using depends on spree_core 2.1, so I installed spree from 2-1-stable branch.